# UseState data not updating before sending fetch request

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I'm currently learning Next.js and React coming from the Angular/Svelte world but am just throwing together a very rough POC and run into an issue where my data doesn't seem to update.

In this particular case, completed_at is firing off as an empty string, if I submit a second time it does have the timestamp. Just wondering how I can resolve this? Doing some reading it looks like I could use useEffect((), but when adding this to the submitCompleted() function I run into an error, as I only want completed_at to have a value if the submitCompleted() function is called, I'm not sure what to do here.

If you have other suggestions for best practices etc let me know as not used to this style of frontend development.

```
export default function CreateTodo() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [timespan, setTimespan] = useState(0);
    const timeSpans = Object.values(TimeSpans);

    const [nextStep, setNextStep] = useState(false);
    const [completed_at, setCompleted_at] = useState('');
    let showMessage;

    async function create() {
        
        await fetch('api-call', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title,
                timespan,
                completed_at
            })
        }
        )
        
        setTitle('');
        setTimespan(0);
        setNextStep(false);
    }

    function submitCompleted() {
        const completed = new Date().toISOString();
        setCompleted_at(completed);
        
        create();
    }
    
    // propably want to wrap these properly and include debouce etc
    if(title !== '' && timespan === 0) {
        showMessage = <div className="card bg-base-100 shadow-xl border border-success flex-row h-16 card-compact mt-4">
            <div className="card-body items-center text-center flex-row">
                <p>Can you do it now?</p>
                <div className="card-actions">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-ghost">No</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={(e) => setNextStep(true)}>Yes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    } 

    if(nextStep) {
        showMessage = <div className="card bg-base-100 shadow-xl border border-success flex-row h-16 card-compact mt-4">
            <div className="card-body items-center text-center flex-row">
                <p>Did you do it?</p>
                <div className="card-actions">
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-ghost">No</button>
                    <button type="button" onClick={(e) => submitCompleted()} className="btn btn-success">Yes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `completed_at` value in async function `create()`. Try This~

```
  async function create() {
    await fetch("/api-call", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        timespan,
        completed_at: new Date().toISOString(),
      }),
    });
    setTitle("");
    setTimespan(0);
    setNextStep(false);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's not always completed_at, only if they click the button with the  `onClick={(e) => submitCompleted()}}`. So the item can be created with or without being completed :)

Comment: Well, based on your code snippet, you do not need to store `completed_at` in state at all. Just pass it as an optional parameter to the `create` function.

Comment: Eventually, I would also like a way to do it without creating the item, i.e a checkbox to mark it as complete.